# Adding a Library so that It can be used in all projects

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2010, parsing, html-parsing

I am attempting to do some Html parsing in a C#. After searching SO for insights into where I should begin, at [Parsing HTML with c#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063203/parsing-html-with-c-net) I found references and high praise of this: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/
I would like to use this in my project but I do not know the correct steps to use a custom Library. After downloading I do not know what to do with the files. I know how to reference the dll. but I am uncertain what to do with the other files(.XML, .PDB)

Step by step instructions would be great.

Comment: What are you having difficulties with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [add a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx) to the DLL.

Once done, you can add a [`using` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423) to your code in order to use the types defined in the library directly.

All the details you need are in the links I posted.