# how can I download all the linked mp3s from a web page?

Tags: c#, winforms, download

how can I download all the linked mp3s from a web page?

example html

```
<a href=​"http:​/​/test.com/linkofmusic1.mp3" download=​"Song.mp3">​
<a href=​"http:​/​/test.com/linkosong2.mp3" download=​"music2.mp3">​
```

Comment: Use HTML parser, get all <a href> filter that one which contains ".mp3"

Comment: You could use DownThemAll http://www.downthemall.net/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing HTML with c#.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063203/parsing-html-with-c-net)

Comment: @LarryBattle He wants to do it using C#. If he wanted to use a tool this wouldn't be the right place to ask it.

Comment: @LarryBattle He needs C# solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples) to get all the link with href having .mp3 extension

**Example:**

```
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.Load("file.htm");

 List<string> mp3Links = new List<string();
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
 {
    if(link != null)
    {
      if(link["href"].EndsWith(".mp3"))
      {
        mp3Links.Add(link["href"].Value);
      }
    }
 }
```