# Trying to get a whole <div> with regex in c#

Tags: c#, html, regex

I'm trying to scrape a whole div element in c#...

I've tried  `div class="txt-block"\s*(.+?)(\r\n?|\n)\s*"` But it doesn't scrape it whole :(
Any ideas?
Here is the div.. THX!

```
    <div class="txt-block" itemprop="creator" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"> 
    <h4 class="inline">Writers:</h4>
    <a href="/name/nm1318843/?ref_=tt_ov_wr" itemprop='url'><span class="itemprop"    itemprop="name">Mark Fergus</span></a>               (screenplay), 
    <a href="/name/nm1319757/?ref_=tt_ov_wr" itemprop='url'><span class="itemprop"         
    itemprop="name">Hawk Ostby</span></a>               (screenplay), <a href="fullcredits?ref_=tt_ov_wr#writers" >6 more credits</a>&nbsp;&raquo;
</div>
```

Comment: You really need to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1583) to understand why RexEx and HTML parsing are not a good idea in conjunction.

Comment: Try an [HTML Parser](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead.

Comment: You can't parse HTML with regex. There are HTML parsers for most languages, look online or HTML parser. If you wish to do it yourself you will need to do a lot more work.

Answer (score 6):

First, the simplex one:

```
(?s)<div.*?>(.*?)</div>
```

Require a particularly named div?

```
(?s)<div[^>]*?class="txt-block"[^>]*?>(.*?)</div>
```

Want to save CPU and avoid unnecessary backtracking?

```
<div[^>]*?class="txt-block"[^>]*?>(([^<]*(?(?!</div>)<))*)</div>
```

The above assumes you don't have nested DIV items.  That's when the whole idea of not using Regex really comes into play.  Unless you are using C#.Net.  In which case you'd just do this:

```
(?xm)
    (?>
        <(?<Tagname>div)[^>]*?class="txt-block"[^>]*>
)
(?(Tagname)
    (
        </(?(?!\k'Tagname')(?<-Tagname>))*\k'Tagname'>(?<-Tagname>)
    |
        (?>
            <(?<Tagname>[a-z][^\s>]*)[^>]*>
        )
    |
        [^<]+
    )+?
    (?(Tagname)(?!))
)
```

Or, the single line version:

```
(?m)(?><(?<Tagname>div)[^>]*?class="txt-block"[^>]*>)(?(Tagname)(</(?(?!\k'Tagname')(?<-Tagname>))*\k'Tagname'>(?<-Tagname>)|(?><(?<Tagname>[a-z][^\s>]*)[^>]*>)|[^<]+)+?(?(Tagname)(?!)))
```

The most complex example I posted won't work in Regex Buddy, but will work in any .Net framework.  Regex Buddy doesn't support Balancing Groups, which is a .Net flavor.

Comment: +1 Fair answer, I feel that Regex is a last resort when doing HTML, but I still give +1 for pointing out some options that can work in limited situations.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing HTML with regex is not a good idea. Try finding a library for parsing HTML in c#.

After a [quick search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063203/parsing-html-with-c-net) I came up with this library: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ It seems that this library has all the functionaility you need.