# Regex for extracting TD content

Tags: c#, regex

I want to extract the values between TDs from this piece of text (html markup).

```
<tr id="pair_169">
   <td id="cr_12cl_last169">16,294.61</td>
   <td>16,294.61</td><td>16,318.11</td>
   <td class="">16,225.25</td>
   <td class="bold greenFont">73.47</td>
   <td class="bold greenFont">0.45%</td>
   <td id="cr_12cl_date169">23/12</td>
</tr>
```

what would be the best Regex pattern?

Comment: you could try using html parser see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063203/parsing-html-with-c-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
const string pattern = @"<td\b[^>]*?>(?<V>[\s\S]*?)</\s*td>";
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(inputText, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
    string value = match.Groups["V"].Value;

    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex

```
<td>(.*?)</td>
```

Or this, but it is used to match exactly TD only with TR

```
(?<1><TR[^>]*>\s*<td.*?</tr>)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old thread but this one helped me for similar situation

```
<td\b[^>]class=".*?>(.*?)<\/td>
```