# \K escape sequence in .NET - to get 3th <TD>

Tags: php, jquery, html, .net, regex

I'm trying to parser this html code:

```
<tr>
  <td>sdafsadf</td>
  <td>12121</td>
  <td>sdafasdf</td>
  <td>32222</td>
  <td>99999</td>
</tr>
```

and get second `<td> the <td>12121</td>` ONLY, I found this link:
[Support of \K in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950/support-of-k-in-regex) and .NET don't support `\K` 
escape sequence, I make the REGEX:

```
(?s)(^(?:(.*?)(\K<td)){2})(.*?</td>)
```

and work fine in http://www.regexr.com/, please help me use this REGEX or similar in .NET.

I'm going crazy and tired because of it

Thanks Regards,

Comment: Any reason you're not using an HTML parser instead?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, i need use REGEX, htmlagilitypack not work for me :( unfortunately

Comment: Why not? Please give more details. Whenever you approach a problem with a known-to-be-tricky-or-infeasible solution instead of a "standard" solution, you should explain clearly *why* you've chosen that route. There may be a tweak to the standard solution that would save you a lot of hassle.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Well, basically because I'm giving maintenance in a program made by others. The program get RAW Strings and parse with REGEX, to I use htmlagilitypack means rewriting all the code. This work is not worth it! :'(. This problem is unique I found to use REGEX

Comment: Okay, so it's not that it won't work, it's that you're persisting with a known-bad solution. Would you actually have to rewrite the whole code, or just part of it? What's the lifetime of this program likely to be?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an HTML parser library like: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

([More on that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063203/parsing-html-with-c-net))

But simply based on your snippet, here's one way:

```cs
 var str = @"
 <tr>
    <td>sdafsadf</td>
    <td>12121</td>
    <td>66666</td>
    <td>32222</td>
    <td>99999</td>
 </tr>";
 var re = new Regex(@"(<td>([^<]+)</td>)", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
 Console.WriteLine(re.Matches(str)[1].Groups[2].Value);
 Console.WriteLine(re.Matches(str)[2].Groups[2].Value);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, on this code sample the REGEX get ALL matches of TD, but the regex: `(?s)(^(?:(.*?)(\K<td)){2})(.*?</td>)` return ONLY ONE match. I need this, REGEX return only one group and one match, but without use \K in .NET