# C# Get text which replaces text from span tags of an HTML code

Tags: c#, html, webclient

I have to do a console application in C# which reads some text from specific webpages. Now I have some problems because I dont know how to read text between  tags.
To begin with, I am downloading the html code from the webpage using WebClient object.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
String htmlCode = client.DownloadString(link);
```

In *htmlCode* string, between  tags I have an image which is a gif of an loading bar.

```
<span id="bitrate_0"><img src="http://webpage.net/images/loading.gif" /></span>
```

If I go to that website from a browser and check that part or if I use Inspect Element feature (which shows me html code) on that part of the webpage, I have a long text (which I need to get).
In addition, in the browser, if I choose to View source, there still are those  tags.

I need to get the text which replaces the gif image. How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: You may need to use a [html parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063203/parsing-html-with-c-net)

Comment: Consider using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to work with HTML in your code.

Comment: ok. I will check both solutions :). Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so you'll have it handy:

- [Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) - codeplex site
- [Html Agility Pack Test Bed](http://haptestbed.codeplex.com/) - great tool if you're going to work with agility pack.
- [XPath tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/) on **w3schools**. You want to read this before you play with Agility.

Having said the above, if you put in the time to go through the above material, you shouldn't have a problem of finding the span and playing around with it.

Good luck :)

Comment: I have read the XPath tutorial from w3schools and now I am trying to use HtmlAgilityPack, but I am having the same problem. The text between <span> remains an image. I need the text from that area.