# Regex for removing complex html tags

Tags: c#, .net, regex, html-parsing

I'm using regex to retrieve text of html pages. I'm eliminate html tags using this regex:

`<[^>]+>`

Problem is this Regex won't work correctly on html tags like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="if (a > b) do_somthing();">
```

This Regex will match with `<input type="button" onclick="if (a >` and `b) do_somthing();">` will remain.

Which regex should I use to match with this markups?

Comment: Why are you using regex to remove these HTML tags?

Comment: Do not use regular expressions (mandatory [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)). Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063203/parsing-html-with-c-net) previous questions to see how to best parse HTML with C#.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about parsing HTML with RegEx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better and proper way to do achieve this is to use an HTML Parser (like agility HTML pack) to parse your HTML and use according to your requirements.  Parsing HTML with REGEX is hard, error-prone.

Read more: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/273/using-the-htmlagilitypack-to-parse-html-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

As described above read the following link why regex don't work on HTML -> [Don't use regex for HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

As suggested in the comments use an C# HTML parser, like e.g. [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
:%s/<.\{-}[^ ]>
```

`[^ ]>` assures match the `>` not preceded by any white-space.