# C# Regex change replacement string for each match

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like this:

```
string s = "<p>Hello world, hello world</p>";
string[] terms = new string[] {"hello", "world"};
```

I want to do a replacement on this string such that each word (case-insensitive) will be matched, and replaced with a numbered index span tag like so:

```
<p>
    <span id="m_1">Hello</span> 
    <span id="m_2">world</span>, 
    <span id="m_3">hello</span> 
    <span id="m_4">world</span>!
</p>
```

I tried doing it like this.

```
int match = 1;
Regex.Replace(s,
    String.Join("|", String.Join("|", terms.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length)
        .Select(Regex.Escape))),
    String.Format("<span id=\"m_{0}\">$&</span>", match++),
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

The output is something like this:

```
<p>
    <span id="m_1">Hello</span> 
    <span id="m_1">world</span>, 
    <span id="m_1">hello</span> 
    <span id="m_1">world</span>!
</p>
```

Where all the ids are the same (m_1) because the regex doesn't evaluate match++ for each match, but one for the whole Regex. How do I get around this?

Comment: May be easier to parse the html and iterate the span nodes, take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063203/parsing-html-with-c-net

Comment: Does it have to be Regex? Looks like a loop with compare would be a simpler and more readable approach.

Comment: @ferflores I am parsing it, but the input has no span nodes. That is the desired output and the actual output. The input is that string up there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is to convert the replacement argument from a string pattern to a match evaluator (`m => String.Format("<span id=\"m_{0}\">{1}</span>", match++, m.Value)`):

```
string s1 = "<p>Hello world, hello world</p>";
string[] terms = new string[] {"hello", "world"};
var match = 1;
s1 = Regex.Replace(s1,
        String.Join("|", String.Join("|", terms.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length)
            .Select(Regex.Escape))),
    m => String.Format("<span id=\"m_{0}\">{1}</span>", match++, m.Value),
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Console.Write(s1);
// => <p><span id="m_1">Hello</span> <span id="m_2">world</span>, <span id="m_3">hello</span> <span id="m_4">world</span></p>
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/dbVx6C)