# Parsing with regex between html tags

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I'm trying to extract text between html tags on this way:

```
 var regex = new Regex(@"<td>ID zahtjeva: <b>"".*?""</b></td>");

 var match = regex.Match(@"<td>ID zahtjeva: <b>438398694</b></td>");

 var result = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

The result should be text between `<b> </b>` tags but I get empty string. I'm not sure what I miss in regex.

Comment: The normal recommendations is not to use regex with html.  html is not regular and regex is meant for regular expressions.  The recommendations are to parse html with a html method not regex.

Comment: +1 to what @jdweng said. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063203/parsing-html-with-c-net). Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your regex like this...

```
var regex = new Regex(@"<td>ID zahtjeva: <b>(.*?)</b></td>");
```

Answer (score 3):

Your regex should be the following (assuming you're only matching numbers):

```
var regex = new Regex(@"<td>ID zahtjeva: <b>(\d+)</b></td>");
```

Your previous regex was searching for `"` characters, which don't exist in your sample code. You also need to define a capturing group via `()`.

Comment: @Josef In that case, `(\d+)` should become `(.+)`, or `(.*?)` (see caner's answer) if it's possible to be empty.

Answer (score 2):

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.90).aspx) :

```
\b  
Start the match at a word boundary.  
(?<word>\w+)  
Match one or more word characters up to a word boundary. Name this captured group word.
\s+  
Match one or more white-space characters.  
(\k<word>)  
Match the captured group that is named word.  
\b
Match a word boundary.
```

So for your problem , it would be

```
var regex = new Regex(@"<td>ID zahtjeva: <b>(.*?)</b></td>");
```